# How to make a circular list in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, circular-list

I want to make a `circular LinkedList` in Java. I have a polygon which contains a list of points. The `list` need to be circular.

I thought to create circular list: `CircularList extends LinkedList` but I don't know how can I continue.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: please show your work

Comment: why does it need to be circular?

Comment: You should have a look at Google first. Here you're
http://www.cs.williams.edu/~bailey/JavaStructures/doc/structure5/structure5/CircularList.html

Comment: is there any reason why you need this list circular? does your problem requires that, or is it to ease navigating around the polygon's points bidirectionally?

Comment: @the question why it has to be circular: i really guess that it's for educational reasons. Also if the question is for a specific data structure in my opinion in the most cases it makes no sense at all to ask why this specific data structure is used because the answer will mostly be: that's what was demanded!

Answer (score 2):

`LinkedList` has 2 references to the first and the last node in the list.

From `LinkedList` [source code](https://github.com/bpupadhyaya/openjdk-8/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#L94):

```java
/**
 * Pointer to first node.
 * Invariant: (first == null && last == null) ||
 *            (first.prev == null && first.item != null)
 */
transient Node<E> first;

/**
 * Pointer to last node.
 * Invariant: (first == null && last == null) ||
 *            (last.next == null && last.item != null)
 */
transient Node<E> last;
```

As you see the first node has it's "prev" member set to null and the last node has the "next" member set to null. 
Setting first.prev= last and last.next=prev will make a circular list, BUT (careful here) you will have to override most insert, link and delete operations in linkedlist to accomodate for this change. You may need to write some code for the iterator too.
It's not trivial because you will need to track where to stop when iterating the list or you may get in an infinite loop.
Hope I made myself clear and the answer helps.
Regards

Comment: There are some implementations of CircularList already implemented you may google it and see it they fulfill  your needs

Comment: why are those variables ``transient``

Comment: Additional information for your answer http://www.cs.williams.edu/~bailey/JavaStructures/doc/structure5/structure5/CircularList.html

Comment: @Andei  *transient* use to indicate skip these value in serialization

Answer (score 1):

Here is quick fix for you.

Check following code to make a `circular LinkedList` in Java.

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
        CircularLinkedList cl = new CircularLinkedList();
        cl.add(1);
        cl.add(2);
        cl.add(3);
        cl.add(4);
        cl.display();
    }

    public class Node{
        int data;
        Node next;
        public Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
    public Node head = null;
    public Node tail = null;
    public void add(int data){
        Node newNode = new Node(data);
        if(head == null) {
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
            newNode.next = head;
        }
        else {
            tail.next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
            tail.next = head;
        }
    }
    public void display() {
        Node current = head;
        if(head == null) {
            System.out.println("List is empty");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Nodes of the circular linked list: ");
             do{
                System.out.print(" "+ current.data);
                current = current.next;
            }while(current != head);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Hope this example helps you understand the concept of `circular LinkedList`.

Answer (score 0):

I have polygon which compose of a list of points. I have class Point, Polygon and ListCircular. 
This is that I've maded :

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ListCircPoly <Point> extends LinkedList {
    private Node node;
    private Node last;
    private int size;

    public ListCircPoly()
    {
        super();
        node=null;//Création d'une chaine vide
        last=null;
        size=0;
    }
    /**
     * @pre /
     * @post ajoute une valeur en fin de list
     * @param s valeur à stocker
     * @return 
     */

    @Override
    public boolean add(Object s)
    {
        if (size==0)//Si la chaine est vide
        {
            this.node= new Node(s);
            this.node.next=this.node;
            last=node;
            size=1;
        }
        else
        {
            Node addNode= new Node(s);
            addNode.next=last.next;
            last.next=addNode;
            last=addNode;
            size++;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        if (size>0)
        {
            System.out.println(this.node.data);
            Node currentNode=this.node.next;
            while (currentNode!=this.node)
            {
                System.out.println(currentNode.data);
                currentNode=currentNode.next;
            }
        }
        else System.out.println("Lise vide");

    }
    private class Node
    {
        private Object data;
        private Node next;

        public Node(Object data)
        {
            this.data=data;
            this.next=null;
        }
    }
 }
```

I want to use it like a linkedList but I have problems in my class Polygon.